# Which algorithm does R use for computing one-class SVM ? (package e1071)

Tags: r, svm, one-class-classification, e1071, novelty-detection

Which algorithm does R use for computing one-class SVM ? This is the function

```
e1071::svm(..., type=one-classification, ...)
```

I have found [this](http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/12/introduction-to-one-class-support-vector-machines/) very nice blog, where author writes about two algorithms for one-class SVM. Which one does the function mentioned use?

Comment: See documentation for `?svm` and links therein (e.g. [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.ps.gz)). I did not dig into the math, but if my scanning of the literature at the end of the document is correct as CTRL+f is not working for me in this document, authors of the code only cite Schölkopf. Happy reading! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the following link: 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf

The link shows the *dual problem* formulation of the SVM algorithm this package uses (when one use *one-class SVM*, page 7 index (3)), easy transformation from the *dual* to the *primal* problem shows that this default implementation is the one **Schölkopf** suggested, see paper:
https://www.stat.purdue.edu/~yuzhu/stat598m3/Papers/NewSVM.pdf